# Reading from external html based on class

Tags: php, html, dom

I try to extract from external source of a html page the entire line of `4G Network` wich actual is `LTE 700 MHz Class 17 / 1700 / 2100 - for AT&T` but in other situations it could be more different like `LTE 850 / 900 / 1700 / 2100` or others.

Title of my result is always stable(`4G Network`) and it is under `<td class="ttl">` and the result is under `<td class="nfo">` class, but both of them are under `<tr>`, so I think based on title `ttl class` is possible to read content founded under `nfo class`

This is the source of external html:

```
<tr>
<th rowspan="8" scope="row">General</th>
<td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">2G Network</a></td>
<td class="nfo">CDMA 800 / 1900 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nfo">GSM 900 / 1800 / 1900 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">3G Network</a></td>
<td class="nfo">HSDPA 2100 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nfo">CDMA2000 1xEV-DO </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">4G Network</a></td>
<td class="nfo">LTE 700 MHz Class 17 / 1700 / 2100 - for AT&amp;T</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=sim">SIM</a></td>
<td class="nfo">Micro-SIM</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="#" onclick="helpW('h_year.htm');">Announced</a></td>
<td class="nfo">2012, October</td>
</tr>
```

this is the code i using:

```
<?php
include_once('/simple_html_dom.php');
$dom = file_get_html("http://www.externalsite.com/pantech_vega_no_6-5268.php");
// alternatively use str_get_html($html) if you have the html string already...
 foreach ($dom->find('td[class=nfo]') as $node)
{
$result = $node->innertext;
$bresult = explode(",", $result);
echo $bresult[0];
} 
?>
```

And the result of my code is this:

`CDMA 800 / 1900 GSM 900 / 1800 / 1900 HSDPA 2100 CDMA2000 1xEV-DO LTE 700 MHz Class 17 / 1700 / 2100 - for AT&T Micro-SIM 2012, October`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get 4G Networks you should do it like this:

```
<?php
include_once('/simple_html_dom.php');
$dom = file_get_html("http://www.gsmarena.com/pantech_vega_no_6-5268.php");
foreach ($dom->find('tr') as $node) {
    if (is_a($node->children(0), 'simple_html_dom_node')) {
        if ($node->children(0)->plaintext == "4G Network") {
            echo $node->children(1)->plaintext;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes yes yes, verry nice code Danilo, thankyou verry much, I apreciate!

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through all results while you only want the first one. So don't loop and get the first result:

```
$results = $dom->find('td[class=nfo]');
$node = reset($results);    // get the first element of the array
//the rest of your code:
$result = $node->innertext;
// etc.
```

Comment: I've edited the question, so my result is not first element `nfo class`

Answer (score 0):

You just want the first result so you can stop after you found it and have your result

```
foreach ($dom->find('td[class=nfo]') as $node){
   $result = $node->innertext;
   break;
}
```

Comment: The source of external is not complete, upper is other `td class` texts, i will edit the question.